# Login to Baasbox application

Tags: rest, curl, postman, mbaas, baasbox

I am trying to login to my BaasBox application via POSTMAN extension. But I am unable to do so. I am unsure of where am I going wrong. Here is the image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/CibCb.png

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should set the content-type to **x-www-form-urlencoded** as specified in the error message

You can set that by clicking the middle button in the request section of Postman
above the textarea where you are setting the json body with username/password/appcode.

Comment: Can you check by clicking the header(2) button in the top right corner that the content-type header is present and that its value is set to "x-www-form-urlencoded" ?

Comment: No, it the Content-Type was set to `application/json`. I changed it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` amnd it worked!

Thanks :)